# talend: The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean

Tags: postgresql, boolean, talend, jobs, tmap

I want to copy the data from table1 of database db1 to table2 of database db2 using talend.
I created a job like presented in the following
[image]

[image]

the two tables has the same schema :

```
   table packaging_method
     id : bigint
     code : varchar
     is_default : boolean
```

I got the compilation this error :   talend: The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot of your tMap ?

Comment: I got the same error with the double type!!

Answer (score 0):

The boolean type is represented as `TINYINT` in MySQL. Change your input and output components schema to use the `integer` java type, and `TINYINT` as database type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am using PostgreSQL and it is represented as boolean. I am encountering the same problem with double precision type

Comment: I'm sorry, they looked like MySQL components. But something doesn't seem right in your mapping. You have a "boolean" type, but when I setup the same, I get the "Boolean" (object type), as opposed to the "boolean" primitive you have in your mapping. What version of Talend are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok THAT was obvious (sorry I am a newbie in Talend),

I just had to set the primitive fields as nullable in the tmap so that these fields are converted to object types.